# Run individual python import statements which are stored in a list

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.7, python-import, try-except

I have a list of libraries i'd like to import, but some of them may not be in the filesystem.

Basically, i want to do something like this:

```
list_of_imports = ['from path1.path2.path3 import x', 'from path1.path2.path4 import y', 'from path1.path2.path3 import z', 'from path1.path2.path2 import a']

for statement in list_of_imports:
    try:
        execute statement
    except:
        ignore error and import the next statement
```

The reason i want to do this, is because some of the libraries in the list may not be in the filesystem, and i don't want one failure to make the entire file to throw an import error.

How do i do this?

Comment: Change `execute statement` to `exec(statement)` and `ignore error and import the next statement` to `pass` and you are good to go

Comment: If you really need to do this dynamically, instead of making a list of statements to execute, it's better to make a list of modules to try to load, then write a function that uses `importlib` (see the [examples](https://docs.python.org/3/library/importlib.html#examples)) to try to load each one, then call that function on each element of the list. But if you _must_ use statements for some reason, you can [`exec`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#exec) them.

Comment: Meanwhile, how do you plan to deal with modules that failed later in you code? You don't want a `try: x.spam` `except NameError: pass` every time you want to use `x`, do you? If you can provide a realistic example, it will be easier to show you a complete answer. (You can write it with static `try: from path1.path2.path3 import x except: pass`, and then ask how to make those try-imports dynamic and less repetitive.)

Comment: Thanks for pointing out the flaw in my approach, @abarnert.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try like this:

```
list_of_imports = ['from path1.path2.path3 import x', 'from path1.path2.path4 import y', 'from path1.path2.path3 import z', 'from path1.path2.path2 import a']

for statement in list_of_imports:
    try:
        exec(statement)
    except ImportError as e:
        continue
```

Explanation:

Iterating over each element from the list using `exec()` you can execute those `import` statements. So if there is no error it will import that modules

Comment: @Randomly Named User: This is tested in my PC.Did you got the required one ?

Comment: That's sounds great !!

Answer (score 1):

First, you probably don't actually want to do this—and if you explained why you think you do, we could probably show you a better way to do it.

But there are some cases where it might be reasonable. For example, I could imagine a `PYTHONSTARTUP` file that pre-loads a bunch of modules for an interactive session; as an interactive user, you can then look at what got loaded and decide what to do.

---

If you only need a handful of these, it's probably best to do them explicitly:

```
try:
    from path1.path2.path3 import x
except ImportError:
    pass
try:
    from path1.path2.path4 import y
except ImportError:
    pass
try:
    from path1.path2.path3 import z
except ImportError:
    pass
```

---

For anything other than interactive use, you're probably going to actually want something like `x = None` rather than `pass`, unless you want to wrap a bunch of `try:`/`except NameError:` tests all over your code.

```
try:
    from path1.path2.path3 import x
except ImportError:
    x = None
# etc.
```

---

If you want to make each one a 1-liner instead of a 4-liner, you can do that using [`importlib`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/importlib.html#examples), at the cost of repeating yourself:

```
from importlib.util import find_spec
if find_spec('path1.path2.path3.x'): from path1.path2.path3 import x
if find_spec('path1.path2.path4.y'): from path1.path2.path4 import y
if find_spec('path1.path2.path3.z'): from path1.path2.path3 import z
```

---

If you need to do a whole bunch of these, you may be better off writing a wrapper function, using `importlib` again:

```
import importlib
def try_import(mod):
    try:
        return importlib.import_module(mod)
    except ImportError:
        return None
x = try_import('path1.path2.path3.x')
y = try_import('path1.path2.path4.y')
z = try_import('path1.path2.path3.z')
```

---

If you have a dynamically-generated list of modules, you need to figure out how you want to store the results, because presumably you also need to *access* them dynamically. One obvious possibility is to stick them into a dict:

```
import importlib
def try_import(mod):
    try:
        return importlib.import_module(mod)
    except ImportError:
        return None
names = ['path1.path2.path3.x', 'path1.path2.path4.y', 'path1.path2.path3.z']
mods = [try_import(name) for name in names]
mods = {name.split('.')[-1]: mod for name, mod in zip(names, mods)}
```

… or, if you want to skip missing modules instead of using `None`:

```
mods = {name.split('.')[-1]: mod for name, mod in zip(names, mods) if mod}
```

… or, if this is for something quasi-static, like the interactive example, maybe a namespace, so you can just access `mods.x`:

```
import types
mods = types.SimpleNamespace(**mods)
```

… or, if you want to dump them into globals, so you can access them as `x`, that's just as simple:

```
globals().update(mods)
```

---

If you really need to build a list of statements rather than a list of modules, use [`exec`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#exec):

```
statements = ['from path1.path2.path3 import x', 'from path1.path2.path4 import y']
for statement in statements:
    try:
        exec(statement)
    except ImportError:
        pass
```

But notice that, besides having to repeat yourself a lot more this way than with the other dynamic options, you also can't do anything sensible like `x = None` without parsing the statement inside the `exec` block, because otherwise you don't have the name `x`. That isn't exactly *hard* in this case, but it adds even more complexity, and code smell…

Comment: Amazing effort put into the answer, appreciate it!